# Images aren't being returned from contributor search or contributor fetch eyeQ Video Explore API's

Tags: gracenote

I'm trying to get contributor images using the eyeQ Video Explore Contributor_Search and Contributor_Fetch API's, but I haven't seen a single actor for which an image is returned. I even tried with Tina Fey, the contributor used in all of the examples. I've specified the SELECT_EXTEND parameter to "IMAGE" and "CONTRIBUTOR_IMAGE" but still no contributor images are returned. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
-travis

Comment: This seems to be working for me, but if you could please add the exact query you used (please obscure your Client and User ID's), and the response you are receiving, we might notice something. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it turned out to be an entitlement issue with my client ID. I was already assisted over email. Thanks!